# How to scroll to the bottom of an element?

Tags: javascript, dom, scroll, scrollview, webapi

I am trying to make the page scroll to the bottom of an element, but I would like to use the bottom of the screen as a reference and not its top.

All `scroll API's` I know only use the top of the screen as a reference, like this:

```
element.scrollTo({
  top: 100,
  left: 100,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

I have the `top property`, but I'd like something like that:

```
element.scrollTo({
  bottom: 100,
  left: 100,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

Of course, this doesn't work, it's just an example. Here I would have the bottom of the screen as a reference and align it with my element's bottom.

Is there anything like that?

I know I could do `offsetTop + element's height` (or something like that) and use the result as the `top value`, but I'd like to know if is there a more straightforward way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [`.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView):

```
element.scrollIntoView(false);
```

or (the same):

```
element.scrollIntoView({block: 'end'});
```

Comment: It was my first attempt, but it didn't work as I expected. My component gets stretched or shrunk depending on the user's action, and this API doesn't seem to follow it.

Comment: @Berg_Durden ok. As far as I know, there is no other solution without using some of height/offset params.

Comment: I see. I'm already doing the calculation and it's working fine. I'll keep that for now and if I find something along the way I can change it. Thank you for your time anyway.